# Need to retrieve Facebook page info from browser cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, facebook

I'm trying to retrieve content from a Facebook page that's no longer available that I viewed and posted on earlier this week.  On my Mac, I've found the folder Library > Caches > Google > Chrome > Default, but I don't know what to do from there.  There are 3 folders: Cache, Code Cache, and Storage, but I don't see images or understandable content in these folders, just code and text.  Can you help?  Thank you very much!